# from unknown error: archive error: (unknown error: could not write file to temp dir), entry error: (unknown error: leftover data after zip entry)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenoid, ruby-2.5, parallel-tests

I am running parallel scenarios on remote using selenoid but after some time and after some scenarios got passed, they fail because of following error while file upload.

> `unknown error: unable to unzip 'file' from unknown error: archive error: (unknown error: could not write file to temp dir), entry error: (unknown error: leftover data after zip entry)`

But When I run one of that failing scenario again, it passes with no error.
I am using parallel_split_test gem to divide scenarios, selenoid for remote testing, Selenium-webdriver vrsion (3.142.7) and ruby 2.5.5

Comment: This does not seem to be Selenoid error. Probably your browser is being launched locally instead.

Comment: No they all are  running on selenoid which I can see by enabling VNC. They first run without failure but after some time they start failing

Comment: And they run perfectly on local without failures.